# Hybris backoffice extend widget

Tags: widget, sap-commerce-cloud, zul, backoffice

[image]

This is the syncronization popup (com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.syncpopup.SyncPopupController) used to synchronize catalogs . I want to modify this OOTB widget in order to add multiple selection instead of one (right now , you can only select one catalog at a time).

How can I achieve this ? I don't know how to extend backoffice widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Listbox` you're trying to modify has an attribute called `multiple`. By default at initialization this is false. The widget lists (because there are 2 lists, one for stage->online and one for online->stage) doesn't have this attribute set to `true` when the widget is created. The `initialize()` method from the `SyncPopupController` only fill these lists with items but nothing more.

Now that you know the root of the problem, you can read [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bda5dec866910148593fca2c20f6a0e.html#loio8bda5dec866910148593fca2c20f6a0e) tutorial which explains you how you can extend a widget *mot-a-mot*. One solution could be extending the original controller and make your custom configuration in the `initialize()` method.

This could look like this:

```
public class ExtendedSyncPopupController extends SyncPopupController
{
   public void initialize(Component component){
       super.initialize(component);
       super.getPullList().setMultiple(true);
       //etc.
   }
}
```

And after this, you can override the widget definition ( **Overriding the Widget Definition** chapter from the tutorial provided above ) and pass your custom controller class in `<controller class="ExtendedSyncPopupController">`.